# WebStorm IDE not suggesting properly

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am using WebStorm IDE with their suggested types-def and it's working on most of the cases. The problem is that when I use:

```
const {Project} = require('../db/models/projects')
```

instead of:

```
const Project = require('../db/models/projects').Project
```

it does not suggest any of the mongoose methods for the model Project.

Do you have any tip for solving this issue?

Comment: looks like a known issue with destructured `require()`; see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000761984-Unresolved-function-or-method